# Scraping Table from Nasdaq (beginner)

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

url = https://www.nasdaqtrader.com/trader.aspx?id=TradeHalts

I am trying to grab the table from the url above. However, when I try to find the table using beautifulsoup, I am unsuccessful. I simply get an empty list.

Please help.

Thanks

```
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get("https://www.nasdaqtrader.com/trader.aspx?id=TradeHalts")

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "lxml")


item = soup.find(class_="genTable")


print(item)
```

Comment: That page seems to be using Ajax to load the table. How are you retrieving the HTML?

Comment: We can't help without seeing your code. What have you tried already?

Comment: Could you share us the code that you have written so far?

Comment: show us the code first

Comment: @RajanChahan I have added the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the code is quite clear, but if you have any questions feel free to ask.

```
headers = {"Referer": "https://www.nasdaqtrader.com/trader.aspx?id=TradeHalts"}
data = {"id":2,"method":"BL_TradeHalt.GetTradeHalts","params":"[]","version":"1.1"}
url = "https://www.nasdaqtrader.com/RPCHandler.axd"
req = requests.post(url, json=data, headers=headers)
result = req.json()['result']
soup = BeautifulSoup(result, 'html.parser')
table = soup.find('table')
```